# How and where do I perform business logic on Doctrine 2 ORM results in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

I am attempting to learn Symfony 3 / Doctrine 2 coming from a Kohana 3.x background and not only wish to move to this more current framework but want to shed my old bad habits and do things the correct way.

I have used ORM before but have discovered in the past that if you are trying to use it for more than just basic queries, ORM can get in the way and so my practice in the past has been to avoid ORM and go with more basic ways to query data.

So if you are reading this my question is about business logic. I've been told that Doctrine entities are supposed to be basic table layout, relationships, indexes, ... pretty much just table schema layout. So where does business logic go?

What I am asking for is if someone can show me the correct way to solve this very simple issue and show me the "standard" way it is supposed to be done. To do this I'll describe the 4 tables I need to join together and give you the 1 piece of business logic that is keeping me from getting this to work in my project. So here are my tables which I will eliminate as many fields as I can to get my point across:

> **Table: *product***
>  
>   id - integer(11) auto_inc
>  name - string(255)
>  crawled_site - string(255)
>
> **Table: *product_categories***
>  id - integer(11) auto_inc
>  name - string(255)
>
> **Table: *product_attributes***
>  id - integer(11) auto_inc
>  
>   product_id - int(11) (relationship to product::id)
>  type - int(11)
>   (type "1" is a product category)
>  value - int(11) (related to
>   productCategories::id)
>
> **Table: *product_images***
>  id - integer(11) auto_inc
>  product_id - int(11) (related to product::id)
>  name - string(255)

Now here is the next piece you'll need. The TWIG template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{product.imgname}}">
        <h1 class="name">{{product.name}} - {{product.crawledSite}}</h1>
        <em class="text-red1 half-bottom">
            <a href="#">{{product.catname}}</a>
        </em>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In the template above the 'catname' and 'imgname' are your place-holders for the productImages::name data and productCategories::name respectively.

Lastly here is the BIG question. The business logic and where to put it. The product images table does not store the path to the image in the webroot. Let us just pretend the images might get moved to Amazon S3 or perhaps were gonna put them on a different external device, image farm, etc so we avoid putting the path in the database. How and where do I put business logic to change the image name or pass along the path with my database results to that the img src tag in my twig template displays the proper full path. In this particular example the logic goes that if the crawled_site for a product is "google.com" for example, the path is /home/web/images/a but if it was "yahoo.com" then the path is /home/web/images/b. So if our product is has a crawled_site with the value of "google.com" and the product "name" field has a value of "1234.jpg", then the path we'd need to give to twig is /home/web/images/a/1234.jpg.

So how do I do this? Could you show me your controllers, entities, and repositories and whatever you used to get this to work? Please keep in mind I'm looking for the "proper" way to do this, not a hack or work-around. Thanks!

Comment: business logic should written into services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: Ok @goldlife, show me how to modify my ORM records returned by Doctrine so that my image paths are correct. Can you show me how to do that with a service?